# My button text does not want to update in C#

Tags: c#

Hallo fellow programmers.

I am busy with an AI project at our university. The project is about writing AI for a 15 puzzle game. The program must solve the puzzle but it needs to show the steps that the computer makes. My code works and my puzzle solve but for some reason my text does not update on the form itself. I can't understand why my text does not update because my code should do it automatically. This is my last bug and if I can fix it then my project is done.

Here is my code for my button text update

```
private void setButtText()
        {
            Button[,] temp = new Button[4, 4];
            temp = (Button[,])buttOpen[0];
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                    butt[i, j] = temp[i, j];               

        }
```

the variable `butt` is an 2d array that has its address set to each of the buttons on my form for example:

```
butt[0,0] = button1;
butt[0,1] = button2;
...
...
butt[3,3] = button16;
```

buttOpen is an arrayList which keeps the button sets of each possible move that the computer can take and position 0 represents the best move the computer can take.

Also I realized that if I set `butt[i,j].Text = temp[i,j].Text` that the text in temp somehow changes but the buttons start to update on my form. I can't understand how it is possible because I am not changing the text of `temp` and if my text in `temp` changes my program crashes. If you have any idea on what might be the problem then please show my errors.

Thank you for your time.

Francois

Comment: i haven't read the whole thing yet, but you do realize that `setButtText` is funny, right?

Comment: To much to read ? Me and my friend did make jokes about it.

Comment: `My program crashes` - Well what error is it throwing? Also is the code that is updating the UI in the UI thread?

Comment: @DarkBee It spews out an array out of bound error in another methood but it is because the text is mixed up and my blank space gets removed from the bord. The text changes in temp it self during the loop and I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

```
butt[i, j] = temp[i, j];
```

This doesn't set Button1 = temp[x]; it overwrites the reference stored in your butt.

`butt[i,j].Text = temp[i,j].Text;` **gets** the button in that location from your butt array and sets it's text, since you've already **set** these buttons to be ones on your form this works to update the text.

Presumably you update the text in the buttOpen array? since that's what you set temp to be.

Note that these lines:

```
        Button[,] temp = new Button[4, 4];
        temp = (Button[,])buttOpen[0];
```

could be condensed into

```
Button[,] temp = (Button[,])buttOpen[0];
```

You're not actually using the newly created button array. Your bug where it crashes probably relates to how you set up buttOpen

Comment: My text in `temp` changes if I use `temp[i,j].Text` but what I found interesting is that when I run it through the loop and add a MessageBox before the text is set and after, I realize that the blank space the computer decided to replace with the number does not change but the number does indeed take the blank space's place. Also I saw that the blank space in `temp` changes when the loop reach its coordinates but it should only change the `butt` text. Each number and the blank space on the board represent a text on a button.